# Costs associated with starting an LLC in Massachusetts?

Tags: united-states, small-business, limited-liability-company, massachusetts

I am going to be starting a LLC business (wedding photography) and I was curious about the associated costs. The business will be registered in Massachusetts. I understand that an exact number may not be possible to determine but if I could get some idea of what to expect, that'd be great.  A breakdown would be great as well.

Note:  I understand that a lawyer and accounting will need to be hired.

Comment: Your question might be better answered at http://answers.onstartups.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's $500 to start (certificate of organization) and $500 per year after that (for an annual report).

Start here: http://1.usa.gov/haxLUB

And that's just for the state to recognize you as an LLC.

Comment: Wow--that's expensive!  In Colorado, I think it cost $25 to register and $10 a year to setup an LLC.

Comment: I wonder how that would compare to obtaining professional liability insurance as a wedding photographer and operating as a sole proprietor (no LLC).  A quick look shows that there are insurers who seem to handle this sort of thing.